# Million people OR million of people OR million & Singular or Plural

Tags: grammatical-number, ielts

So far, I've learned:

> 1) A number of internet users were in Paris.
>
> 2) The number of internet users was in Paris.

1) and 2) are grammatically correct, and have a little different meanings.

---

---

But I'm not sure about:

> - `<Number>` + of + plural noun/nouns . . .
> - `<Unit>` + of + plural noun/nouns . . .
> - `<Number>` + plural noun/nouns . . .
> - `<Unit>` + plural noun/nouns . . .

**1. Should we treat `"<Number> + of + plural noun/nouns"` and `<Unit> + of + plural noun/nouns"` as `"A number of"`?**

a) `7.8 million of internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

b) `Millions of internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

c) `7.8 million internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

d) `Millions internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

---

---

**2.** I know that we can usually say `"Millions of internet users"` and `"7.8 million internet users"`.

**How about saying `"Millions internet users"` and `"7.8 million of internet users"`, are they usual?**

---

---

**3.** Is it usual to use article `"the"` to specify the mentioned quantities in the sentences?

**And should we treat `"The <number> + of + plural noun/nouns"` and `The <unit> + of + plural noun/nouns"` as `"The number of"`?**

e) `The 7.8 million of internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

f) `The millions of internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

g) `The 7.8 million internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

h) `The millions internet users` was/were in Paris. < **[Was](http://#) || [Were](http://#)** >

---

---

**4.** ***In 2005, Paris had the largest number of internet users at 7.8 ___________.***

**Which should be filled in the blank?**

a) million people

b) million of people

c) million

Comment: Although (2) is grammatical, it means something quite different from (1) in your opening pair.

Comment: *Users* is plural, so *were* would be the correct choice with any number (other than 1) of them. -- Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Can I say that we treat **"7.8 million of "** as the phrase **"a number of"**? How about **"*the* 7.8 million of "**? Do we treat this as the phrase **"the number of"**?

Comment: I thought they were related questions, and I'm kind of a newbie here :( @michael.hor257k

Comment: Thank you for your kindness, @Lawrence. Can you share some ideas about question 1., 2., 3. and 4. with me please?

Comment: You're welcome. Follow your intuition in your Q2. Upon re-reading your question, I think there's an interesting element that you should highlight (by editing the question). That is, why "millions *of*" when the number of millions is left unspecified, but *of* is left off when the number is specified. Then there's also the case where you have "2 million of them were ...", which kind of mixes the previous cases.

Comment: What if I said "**the** 2 million of them", would the following verb be a singular verb? "**the** 2 million of them **was**"? And is it more emphasized with an article "the"? @Lawrence

Comment: That depends on whether you're thinking of the group as separate individuals (plural agreement) or a monolithic group (singular agreement). Compare: *the 2 million of them were well-prepared* vs *the 2 million of them was a force to be reckoned with*.

Comment: So, the conclusion is, neither `"The <number> + of + plural noun/nouns"` and `The <unit> + of + plural noun/nouns"` nor `"<Number> + of + plural noun/nouns"` and `<Unit> + of + plural noun/nouns"` are treated the same as`"The number of"` and `"A number of"`, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of your question is: when to use *of* with numbers. Here's an attempt to collate some use cases and attempt a generalisation.

Use *of* if you 'apply' the number to the noun; leave it off if you simply count them.

Consider the following in light of the various [dictionary entries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/of) for the word "of" relating to the use of the word to express associations or relationships:

- 5 million **of** them: part-whole relationship
- millions **of** people, a lot **of** people: quantifier-noun relationship
- 5 million ( ) people, no ( ) people: simple count

Comment: I'm not particularly happy with my answer in its current form, but I'm leaving the answer up for now in the hope that linguists would chip in, either with their own answers or in comments. It's clear that *of* isn't used uniformly - that's simply a matter of usage. The interesting question is *why*.

Comment: Do we usually say "millions people" without the word "of"?

Comment: @hbtpoprock No, unless "millions" is a description of the people, like "*American* people".

Comment: Thank you again @Lawrence, however if you don't mind me asking, can you help me for the one last thing please? The question 4. is waiting for your answer.

Comment: @hbtpoprock You’re welcome. Both (a) and (c) work with your Q4.